# Error while using constant value in the copy_data

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-apex, oracle-cloud-infrastructure, oracle-cloud-shell

How to use the constant value or sequence in the dbms_cloud.copy_data for the filed_list?

need to pass a constant value in the column of the table its loading in the copy_data and the sequence for a column in the filed list parameter in the copy_data for the position_based

Comment: I think you better create an external table, and use an insert as select from it. This allows you to do whatever you want with the data, including adding sequence numbers and constants.